# How to initialize a Django ModelChoiceField from a view?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views, django-3.0

I have the following model relationship where a task is associated to an objective and an objective is associated to a User. I created a Django form that displays all the objectives that are associated to a User.

```
class DropDownMenuSelectedObjectivesForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_id = kwargs.pop('id')
        super(DropDownMenuSelectedObjectivesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['objective'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Objective.objects.values_list('objective',flat=True)
                                                .filter(accounts=User.objects.get(id=user_id),
                                                status='In Progress'), empty_label=None)
```

When I open my views.py I am able to see all the objectives from the User but **I would like that the Django form dropdown menu could be initialized with the current objective that is associated with a task**.

So far, I have tried the following to initialize the dropdown menu but I've got no success.

```
# views.py

def update_task(request, id):
    '''Update a task'''

    task = Task.objects.get(pk=id)  # get the task id from the db
    associated_task_objective = task.objective.values('objective')[0]
    form = TaskModelForm(request.POST or None, instance=task)

    # Attempt 1 to initialize the ModelChoiceField 
    objective = DropDownMenuSelectedObjectiveForm(id = request.user.id, initial = { 'objective': associated_task_objective})


    if request.method == "GET":
        template_name = 'task/formTask.html'
        return render(request, template_name, {'form': form, 'objective':objective})


# forms.py
class DropDownMenuSelectedGoalsForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_id = kwargs.pop('id')
        super(DropDownMenuSelectedGoalsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Attempt 2 to initialize the ModelChoiceField 
        self.fields['objective'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Objective.objects.values_list('objective',flat=True)
                                                .filter(accounts=User.objects.get(id=user_id),
                                                status='In Progress'), empty_label=None, initial=2)
```

Even if I try to initialize the `ModelChoiceField` from the `forms.py` with a valid pk number, the modelchoicefield doesn't initialize.

Any  idea or suggestion is really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the following to solve this problem:

```
def update_task(request, id):
    '''Update a task'''

    task = Task.objects.get(pk=id)  # get the task id from the db
    associated_task_objective = task.goal.values_list('goal',flat=True)[0]
    form = TaskModelForm(request.POST or None, instance=task)
    objective = DropDownMenuSelectedObjectiveForm(id = request.user.id, initial = { 'objective': associated_task_objective})
```

The `initial` keyword is looking by name of the objective, not by pk.